# Pandas : Query then groupby and sum, and finally fillna

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do something that seems completely non readable, and I was wondering if I could make it simplier ( And I bet I could, but can't find how ).

This is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('ABC'))
df['D'] = [1,2,2,1,2]

df1 = df.query('B<1')[['A', 'D']].groupby('D').sum().reset_index()

df = df.set_index(['D'])
df1 = df1.set_index(['D'])

df2 = df1.join(df[['B', 'C']], how='inner', on=['D']).reset_index()

df2.loc[df2['B'] > 1, 'A'] = 0

df

          A         B         C
D
1  0.702204  2.288548 -0.251334
2 -0.346842 -1.486899 -0.576246
2 -1.183607 -2.210152  0.409037
1 -0.884401  0.124899  1.719387
2  0.305400  0.988187  0.160168

df2
   D         A         B         C
0  1  0.000000  2.288548 -0.251334
1  1 -0.884401  0.124899  1.719387
2  2 -1.225049 -1.486899 -0.576246
3  2 -1.225049 -2.210152  0.409037
4  2 -1.225049  0.988187  0.160168
```

This is what I came up, and it is correct but not really readable.

I need:

1. To query every line where B < 1
2. Group by another column ( D )
3. Sum a third column ( A )
4. Put 0 in every line not matching query in 1

Is it possible to do that without that ugly code?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First sort values by `D` if need same order like `df2`, then convert `A` to `0` if greater like `1`, so possible use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `sum` for new Series with same size like original DataFrame, last set `0` if `B` is greater like `1` and assign to column `A`:

```
#query 4 use query 1, so possible reuse mask
m = df.B.lt(1)

df['A'] = df['A'].where(m, 0).groupby(df['D']).transform('sum').where(m,0)
print (df)
   D         A         B         C
0  1  0.000000  2.288548 -0.251334
1  2 -1.225049 -1.486899 -0.576246
2  2 -1.225049 -2.210152  0.409037
3  1 -0.884401  0.124899  1.719387
4  2 -1.225049  0.988187  0.160168
```

**How it working:**

```
print (df['A'].where(m, 0))
0    0.000000
1   -1.225049
2   -1.225049
3   -0.884401
4   -1.225049
Name: A, dtype: float64

print (df['A'].where(m, 0).groupby(df['D']).transform('sum'))
0   -0.884401
1   -3.675147
2   -3.675147
3   -0.884401
4   -3.675147
Name: A, dtype: float64

print (df['A'].where(m, 0).groupby(df['D'])
              .transform('sum').where(m,0))
0    0.000000
1   -3.675147
2   -3.675147
3   -0.884401
4   -3.675147
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Indeed, it's quite similar, although my initial answer was about the same (I just realized afterward I had misread on which column to apply), anyway as an act of good faith I'll delete

Comment: @mozway - It was no my purpose, but thanks.

Comment: You should reuse the mask btw, no need to compute it twice

Comment: @mozway - checked I need and possible reuse, thanks.

Comment: Well yes, this was exactly my (now-deleted) answer…

Comment: Thanks a lot to you 2.

I'm just discovering some pandas functions and I knew transform/where, but didn't know how to use it.

It's pretty clear now, thanks again :)